# Hightlight PDF text dynamically with pdfjs

Tags: javascript, highlight, pdf.js

I have an existing html viewer that will add highlights(annotate) certain words and also apply a tool tip to the annotation. Here is an example of the annotation

```
    <span
    data-placement="bottom"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-html="true"
    rel="tooltip"
    id="ann-symp-151-169"
    title=""
    data-original-title="<table class='tooltiptable'>....</tr>"
    class="marked hilite-on symp"
    aria-describedby="tooltip542028"
>
    Hearing and Speech
</span>
<div class="tooltip fade bottom in" role="tooltip" id="tooltip542028" style="top: 702.953px; left: 160.758px; display: block;">
    <div class="tooltip-arrow" style="left: 50%;"></div>
    <div class="tooltip-inner">
        <table class="tooltiptable">
            <tbody>
                ....
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is what the hightlight would look like

[image]

I need to do add the annotation to a pdf.. This is not a user search.. I have the indexes of the word or phrase i need to annotate..

We currenlty use PDFObject with pdfjs to view pdf's ..

If anyone has any good examples of how to do this i would really appreciate it

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.. I did not.. I had a collegue come up with something that sort of worked. but, it is too complicated to put all the code here